# Oneplus One - unlock pattern and/or retrieve data

Tags: adb, data-recovery, oneplus-one, pattern-lock

I have a OnePlus One that went dead 7 years ago with valuable photos (for me) on it. Had it repaired recently, but can't remember the pattern I used back then... Here is what I found out about the software and status of the phone:

- Android 6 with Cyanogenmod (probably version 13, maybe earlier)
- USB debugging disabled
- bootloader is locked
- not rooted
- no TWRP installed

I can get the phone in fastboot mode or in Recovery Mode. The options in recovery mode are:

- Reboot system
- Apply update
- Factory Reset
- Reboot recovery
- Reboot to bootloader
- View recovery logs

All solutions I found while researching was deleting/editing a file that contains the pattern. But that would need a phone with a custom recovery, which I can't install without wiping the phone.

I have a second OPO that was my brother's old phone, which I can use as a testbed to not lose all my data on the other one. One thing I tried with the second phone was to do a hard reset, root it and try to recover data that was deleted by the reset via a recovery software. Using Fonepaw was no success, but maybe there are different, better programs out there?

Comment: If you have a custom ROM installed you should be able to boot into a custom recovery that allows you disk access e.g. via adb (at that time most ROMs did not encrypt the user data) or perform a full user data backup https://twrp.me/oneplus/oneplusone.html

Comment: I can boot into the cyanogenmod recovery that is factory. However I don´'t have access to adb. The recovery itself only has the options I listed in my post, so no file access.

Comment: TWRP recovery what I had linked to in my last comment provides more functionality. Have you tried to boot it?

Comment: How can I install TWRP? When I read the instructions to install TWRP either the phone must be rooted or USB debugging must be enabled. Neither of these apply to me :(

Comment: Sorry I missed that you have re-locked bootloader. Usually a custom ROM like Cyanogenmod automatically means unlocked bootloader.

Comment: Unfortunatly not as the custom ROM was installed by Oneplus which decided to lock the bootloader.. Are there any other options you know about? I found old threads form 2016 about unlocking the bootloader without wiping all the data, but I couldn't find definite solutions